# retry redownload after failed with aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm following this to download multiple huge files from AWS S3

https://github.com/allada/bsc-archive-snapshot/blob/master/build_archive_node.sh

However, I got multiple failures:

```
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
download failed: s3://public-blockchain-snapshots/bsc/6202776-6662396.tar.zstd to - [Errno 32] Broken pipe
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
download failed: s3://public-blockchain-snapshots/bsc/7214671-7292199.tar.zstd to - [Errno 32] Broken pipe
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
download failed: s3://public-blockchain-snapshots/bsc/8029385-8291918.tar.zstd to - [Errno 32] Broken pipe
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
download failed: s3://public-blockchain-snapshots/bsc/6946792-7214799.tar.zstd to - [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

The parts that associated with the failure is:

```
# Query S3 for all archives and download them in parallel to a new zfs dataset.
while IFS= read -r FILE_NAME; do
  ZFS_NAME=$(echo "$FILE_NAME" | cut -d'.' -f1)
  ARCHIVE_NAMES+=("$ZFS_NAME")
  zfs create -o "mountpoint=/$ZFS_NAME" "tank/$ZFS_NAME"
  bash -c "cd /$ZFS_NAME && aws s3 cp --request-payer=requester '$S3_BUCKET_PATH/bsc/$FILE_NAME' - | /zstd/zstd --long=30 -d | tar -xf -" &
done <<<"$(aws s3 ls --request-payer=requester "$S3_BUCKET_PATH/bsc/" | cut -d' ' -f4)"
```

How do i redownload those failed parts?

Comment: Is there any solution except for re-syncing until all files are downloaded?